# Debug output in different terminal windows

Tags: ros, logger

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS_DEBUG_NAMED with different names in my code. Do you know if it's possible to use the terminal to see only the output of a certain debug logger instead of using rxconsole?

I've a windows machine where I want to watch the output from different debug loggers by connecting to my work machine via SSH.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66067/debug-output-in-different-terminal-windows/) by [alex_rockt](https://answers.ros.org/users/5037/alex_rockt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not a text console for viewing filtered rosconsole outputs.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0